# Excel output append

Tags: functions, matrix, output-formatting, output, excel

I currently have the following codes:

```
output = Grid [{{"fiscalyear", "companyname", "keyword1frequency", 
"trapwordfrequency", "keyword-trapword"}, {fiscalyear, 
companyname, keyword1frequency, trapwordfrequency, secondDV}}]

Export[StringJoin["C:\\Users\\MyLaptop\\Desktop\\Test\\", 
TextString[fiscalyear], "_", TextString[companyname], 
".csv"], output]
```

which gets me an excel output with a line that has fiscal year, companyname and other variables.
However, this output has only one line but i want to run my main code more than 100 times such that i could append the next company's information right below (next row) each company. Could anyone help please? The above code would generate 100 excel files if i were to run the code 100 times but i would like one file with 100 rows instead!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have some functions that compute fiscal year, company name, keyword etc. Then you would could use code like this:

```
res= Table[compute[i], {i,1,100}]; 
output= Prepend[res, "Fiscal year", "Company name", ".."]; 
Export["output.xlsx", output]
```